# Java shrink image file to target file size

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I am working on an android app, and the user will take a photo with the camera. The resulting photo can vary in size from < 1 MB to over 3-4 MB. I need to make sure the photo is less than 1 MB, to store it on the server. So for images larger than 1 MB, I want to shrink it to less than 1 MB but keep as much quality as possible. I am not concerned about losing (some) quality.

How can I achieve this? As far as I know most solutions involve shrinking the image to target dimensions (width X height), but in my case I am only concerned with the resulting size of the shrunken image.

And it is very important the result is less than 1 MB, if any margin of error is present it must be on the lower file size, if that makes sense.

Is there a way to calculate what the width and height should be to achieve the target file size? Or better yet, shrink it without specifying width and height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I achieve this?

The big three options are:

- Reduce the resolution (width and height)
- Reduce the JPEG quality (0-100 value that you use when compressing a bitmap to JPEG)
- Reduce the bit depth (e.g., from ARGB888 to RGB565), though this is mostly something for PNGs and I suspect will really ruin your photo quality

> Is there a way to calculate what the width and height should be to achieve the target file size?

No, as it depends quite a bit on the contents of the image and how well it compresses using JPEG's compression algorithms.

> Or better yet, shrink it without specifying width and height?

For getting from 3-4 MB to under 1 MB, it is almost guaranteed that you will need to reduce the resolution.

However, since only you know what you consider to be acceptable output, you will need to experiment yourself to determine how best to apply those three options.

Comment: Sorry I tried my best to say all of my requirements. Really there aren't many. I could do either of the first two of your options. But the question is, by how much do I need to reduce the resolution, or by how much do I need to reduce the JPEG quality. Is there a way to calculate based on file size? Like I said, quality is not my concern, the goal is to shrink as little as possible to get under 1 mb.

Comment: @jefferson: "Is there a way to calculate based on file size?" -- as I wrote, no, as it depends quite a bit on the contents of the image and how well it compresses using JPEG's compression algorithms. You can run some tests with some sample photos and try to come up with a heuristic that you can use. For example, suppose your photo is 4MB. Halving the resolution on each axis (half the width and half the height) would reduce the pixel count to 25% of the original, which should get you near 1MB. The actual image may still be above or below 1MB, though, depending on how the compression works.

Comment: Ok that makes sense thank you. If the file size shrinks with the resolution in a linear relation that is exactly what I was trying to figure out.

Comment: @jefferson: Again, it will not shrink *exactly* in a linear fashion. But resolution is by far the most important component in a JPEG's file size.

Comment: Yes I understand. Will need to test the theory and perhaps set a lower limit that allows for some margin of error.

Answer (score 1):

I did that some 15 years ago using Swing and `javax.image` and the only viable solution was to apply different quality levels to the JPG encoder to find the best quality setting for which the image was still smaller than the requested maximum size. Code went something like this (code here synthesized from actual code, never tested in this version...):

```
/** Create JPG version of some image with given JPG quality setting (0..1), helper method */  
private byte[] createResultBytes(BufferedImage losslessimage,float lossyquality) {
  Iterator<ImageWriter> iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("JPG");
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  if (iter.hasNext()) {
    ImageWriter writer = iter.next();
    ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    iwp.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    iwp.setCompressionQuality(lossyquality);

    MemoryCacheImageOutputStream mcios = new MemoryCacheImageOutputStream(baos);
    writer.setOutput(mcios);

    // workaround for alpha-channel problems with lossy images: Seems to be non-functional for some pictures, anyway.
    BufferedImage img2=new BufferedImage(losslessimage.getWidth(),losslessimage.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g=img2.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(new ImageIcon(losslessimage).getImage(),0,0,null);
    g.dispose();
    IIOImage iioimg = new IIOImage(img2, null, null);
    try {
      writer.write(null, iioimg, iwp);
      mcios.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {}
  }
  return baos.toByteArray();
}

/** Create JPG version of some image with best JPG quality where the file size is still not larger than maxsize. */
public byte[] getLossyImage(BufferedImage losslessimage,int maxsize,float maxquality) {
  byte[] resultbytes=createResultBytes(losslessimage,maxquality);
  if (resultbytes.length>size) {
    int minsize=(int)(size*.9f);
    float newq=maxquality/2f;
    resultbytes=createResultBytes(losslessimage,newq);
    float qdiff=newq/2f;
    while ((resultbytes.length<minsize || resultbytes.length>size) &&  diff>.02f) {
      newq+=(resultbytes.length<minsize?qdiff:-qdiff);
      resultbytes=createResultBytes(losslessimage,newq);
      qdiff=qdiff/2f;
    }
  }
  return resultbytes;
}
```

Note that I only changed the file size by the JPG quality setting, not by automatically change the size of the image. If you want to go that way, you have to apply those size changes first.

Comment: An interesting approach. Thanks for sharing will test this as well.